# R: Subset a data table based on the other one

Tags: r, datetime, join, data.table, subset

Say I have two data table `dm` and `dn`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(12)
dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2015-09-01'),as.Date('2015-11-01'), 2)
dm = data.table(user=sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace=T),
                time=sample(dates, 10)) 

dn = data.table(user=sample(LETTERS[1:8], 3, replace=F),
                start=c(as.Date('2015-09-01'), as.Date('2015-10-05'),  
                        as.Date('2015-09-14')),
                end=c(as.Date('2015-10-30'), as.Date('2015-11-01'),                    
                      as.Date('2015-10-20')))

>dm
#     user       time
#  1:    A 2015-09-25
#  2:    D 2015-10-19
#  3:    D 2015-09-21
#  4:    B 2015-10-27
#  5:    A 2015-09-15
#  6:    A 2015-09-23
#  7:    A 2015-10-21
#  8:    C 2015-10-31
#  9:    A 2015-10-01
# 10:    A 2015-09-05


>dn
#    user      start        end
# 1:    B 2015-09-01 2015-10-30
# 2:    F 2015-10-05 2015-11-01
# 3:    A 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
```

How can one do to subset `dm` based on the columns of `dn`? For example, for each user in `dn`, we look up `dm` for the matched `user` and subset the rows having `time` falling between the `user`'s time interval [`start`, `end`], if there is any.

In this example, the desired outcome is

```
    user       time      start        end
 5:    A 2015-09-15 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
 6:    A 2015-09-23 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
 9:    A 2015-10-01 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
10:    A 2015-09-05 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
 4:    B 2015-10-27 2015-09-01 2015-10-30
```

The row number is retained just for illustration, and the order of time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
setkey(dm,user)
dm[dn][time>start & time<end]   
#   user       time      start        end
#1:    A 2015-09-25 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
#2:    A 2015-09-15 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
#3:    A 2015-09-23 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
#4:    A 2015-10-01 2015-09-14 2015-10-20
#5:    B 2015-10-27 2015-09-01 2015-10-30
```